# Python: Why is the size I'm reading from a file different from sys.getsizeof()?

Tags: python

I have a file that has a size of 10240 bytes. This is my script to get file size:

```
fh = open(name, "r")
data = fh.read(10240)
print sys.getsizeof(data)
```

> Output: 10277

I'm reading 10240 bytes from the file but when I print the size, I get 10277. How do I make sure I don't read more than 10240 bytes? I should be sending 10240 bytes to my Consumer but it looks like it's sending more.

Answer (score 6):

To get the *length* of `data`, use `len(data)`. Assuming your file is sufficiently large enough, `len(data)` will equal 10240; it won't read more than you requested.

[`sys.getsizeof()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) returns the total size of the Python object in memory, including any additional overhead used by the runtime. It is not generally useful in most all Python applications.

Comment: Thanks Jonathon. So how can I read bytes instead of the characters?

Comment: In Python 2, there is no difference. All "buffers" returned from things like `file.read()` are of type `str`, just like any other string.

Comment: @tdelaney `bytes is str` is `True` in Python 2.

Comment: If you open for read without the "b" for binary, python will convert any `\r\n` sequences in the file to `\n`. In python3, it will also try to decode from whatever `sys.getdefaultencoding()` is. So, if its utf-8, `len` will report the number of unicode chars, not bytes.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, yes, that's why I said it will read bytes.

Comment: @tdelaney Regarding the line endings, that is not true in general. On Windows, maybe, but on Linux, no, it will it will not. The behavior you speak of is [*universal line endings*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) and requires the file be opened with `'U'`.

Comment: It does not require the file be opened in any special way if the Python you're using was compiled with universal newline support enabled by default. Which the standard CPython is...

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thank you! So if I have to read the size in bytes without any overhead, I should use len() instead of sys.getsizeof(), right?

Comment: @kindall I'm sorry, but you're mistaken. You have to opt-in to universal newlines in Python 2. See the linked documentation in my previous comment. I just tried it in `Python 2.7.13` from Fedora 24. `echo -en 'two\r\nlines\r\n' >two.txt && python2.7 -c "print repr(open('two.txt', 'r').read())"` will print `'two\r\nlines\r\n'`, which shows that the original CRLF line endings are intact.

Comment: @NoName Just **never** use `sys.getsizeof()`.

Answer (score 2):

[From the Python 3.6 docs:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof)

> getsizeof() calls the object’s **sizeof** method and adds an additional garbage collector overhead if the object is managed by the garbage collector.

So the extra size you're getting from `getsizeof` is actually the garbage collector data Python adds to the `bytes` object so it knows how to delete the data from the file when you're done with it, and any other data only the runtime needs to know about.

When you serialize the `bytes` object to send it to your consumer, this overhead gets thrown away by the serializer, so don't worry. If you need to know how many bytes *actually* get sent, use the `len()` function.